# TimeSeries vs XYSeries AchartEngine

Tags: java, android, charts, time-series, achartengine

XYSeries add method only accepts add(double, double). Why can't it accept add(java.util Date, double) similar to the TimeSeries.

I would like to plot X-axis = dates, 2 Y-axis (left and right) = values but the problem I experienced was I lost the dual y-axis plot (secondary Y-axis on the right hand side) if I use the TimeSeries add method with (Date, double) values. If I use the XYSeries it allows me to do a dual y-axis plot but would not accept Dates in the X-axis.

Code is given below:

```
public void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String[] titles,
    List<Date[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues, int scale) {
    int length = titles.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], scale);
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(titles[i]);
        Date[] xV = xValues.get(i);
        double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
        int seriesLength = xV.length;
        for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
            series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X axis have to share the same values if you really want the line charts be displayed together.

So you will either have to have all the charts X axis be date values or all of them be double values.

Comment: The chart's X-axis are set to date values and it shares the same date values (X1 and X2 has the same date values).

Comment: You can do series.add(date.getTime(), value); in XYSeries.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help. I am now able to display the Date in the x-axis and the dual y axis (left and right).